# Find parameters beginning with a dash in a string

Tags: regex, bash

Assumed one has a string containing parameters:

`echo "-v foo -d --print bar-foo ba-z fOo"`

How can one get parameters beginning with a dash?

`-v -d --print`

Comment: Based on the tag, I believe its `bash`

Comment: preferably bash. But can be perl, awk, ... as well.

Comment: Do you want to use this to parse command line switches of a script? Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ str="-v foo -d --print bar-foo ba-z"
$ for i in $str; do test ${i::1} = - && echo $i; done
-v
-d
--print
```

Note this is an instance where you must *not* quote the variable, since you want word splitting to occur.  (That is, do not write `for i in "$str"`)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

```
 STR="-v foo -d --print bar-foo ba-z fOo"
 echo "$STR" | egrep -o -e "(^| )+--?[^ ]+" | sed -e 's/ //g'
```

Will output:

```
-v
-d
--print
```

If you want to parse options passed to your script, you should consider using `getopt`.

**References:**

- [example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopt-in-bash)