# Assign value of C variable to bash variable

Tags: c, linux, bash

I am writing a program in C that bash code as well. I need to assign the value of a C variable to a bash variable. More specifically I need to assign the argument supplied to C program to bash variable inside same program.

```
int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf(argv[1]);
    system("echo $1"); // Here I need to assign argv[1] to bash variable.
}
```

Comment: create a buffer, write the value into it `sprintf(buf, "echo %s",argv[1])` and use system() on the buffer

Comment: What "bash variable"? How are you going to pass that information from bash to your program? Through the command-line (`$ ./a.out 42 FOO`), maybe?

Comment: @Tommylee2k `sprintf` - that is how you create a vulnerability in your application.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I think that's the least of his problems ;)

Comment: int execle(const char *path, const char *arg, ...
                       /*, (char *) NULL, char * const envp[] */);

Comment: You may prefer to use `unistd.h`'s `int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);` to run your command and pass it arguments.

Comment: Are you attempting to set a variable by running `./myprogram value` from the shell?  You're better off just doing `VARIABLE=vale` directly in the shell.  How exactly do you intend to use the bash variable?  Also, can you clarify what you mean when you say you're "writing a program in C that bash code as well"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variable from c program to shell script as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18179346/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [setenv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) to set an environment variable which is accessible by your script.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setenv("VAR", argv[1], 1);
    system("echo $VAR");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its solved my problem.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in bash: $ `FOOVAR=3; echo $FOOVAR; echo -e '#include <stdlib.h>\nint main(void){setenv("FOOVAR", "42", 1);}' | gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -x c -; ./a.out; echo $FOOVAR` outputs "3 3", not "3 42".

Comment: @pmg, you are using it in a wrong way, because your shell script and system() in c program are not in the same session,  one can simply execute the shell script from the c program, the environment variable will then be made available to the script executed in the code.