# Shell Script parameters

Tags: bash, shell

What is the best way to parse parameters in shell script command, and then validate it?

For example `bash someScript.sh -p <some_path> -o <some_other_param> -i (User forget to provide value)`.

How to parse all of this parameters and when user forget to input some parameters or value of this parameter show some error message and terminate executing of script?

Comment: Use `getopts`, of course. It's described in the bash man page.

Comment: Simple solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101929/bash-script-how-to-test-for-parameter-pairs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [getopt](/questions/tagged/getopt) or [getopts](/questions/tagged/getopts).

There are lots of examples on this site, but here is one more:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

p_set=false
o_set=false
i_set=false
while getopts p:o:i: OPT; do
    case "${OPT}" in
        p)
            p_set=true
            some_path=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        o)
            o_set=true
            some_other_param=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        i)
            i_set=true
            # Process ${OPTARG} or report error if it's not provided
            ;;
    esac
done

if ! $i_set ; then
    echo "-i must be provided"
fi
```

Comment: And how to check when user enter param and forget value?

Comment: I was adding that detail as you commented.

Comment: That can only happen if the user types `-i` (for example) as the last argument when you expect an option. Then `getopts` will report an error.

Answer (score 0):

Search man pages of `getopts`. You would easily implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the `man` page is always a good resource. But there are also good examples on the net. When dealing with `getopts`, I always refer to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035. Pretty much everything you'd want to know can be found there.