# How to split items of a string into two, one contains item start with '-D'?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell, others can pass arguments to it, like:

```
someshell task1 task2 -Daaa=111 -Dbbb=222 task3
```

In the shell, I can get all the arguments with `$@`, which is:

```
task1 task2 -Daaa=111 -Dbbb=222 task3
```

Then I want to get all args start with `-D` out of the string, and make two strings:

```
-Daaa=111 -Dbbb=222
```

and

```
task1 task2 task3
```

I'm not familiar with bash, what I can do now is to split the string and check each item, then group them in someway. Which seems a little complex.

If there is any simple way to do this?

Comment: [getopt might be able to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262143/shell-script-parameters) Perhaps this is a duplicate?

Comment: @col6y 'getopt' is not applicable for my case. I don't need parsing more options, just want to split `-D` with others

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035 for some useful ways to handle command line arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do
    [ ${i:0:2} = -D ] && ar1+=( $i ) || ar2+=( $i )
done

echo "string1: ${ar1[@]}"
echo "string2: ${ar2[@]}"
```

**Output**

```
$ bash myarg.sh task1 task2 -Daaa=111 -Dbbb=222 task3
string1: -Daaa=111 -Dbbb=222
string2: task1 task2 task3
```

Another option:

```
for i in "$@"; do
    [[ $i = -D* ]] && ar1+=( $i ) || ar2+=( $i )
done
```

Full example:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do
    [ ${i:0:2} = -D ] && ar1+=( $i ) || ar2+=( $i )
done

echo "string1: ${ar1[@]}"
echo "string2: ${ar2[@]}"

unset ar1
unset ar2

for i in "$@"; do
    [[ $i = -D* ]] && ar1+=( $i ) || ar2+=( $i )
done

echo "string1: ${ar1[@]}"
echo "string2: ${ar2[@]}"

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash myarg.sh task1 task2 -Daaa=111 -Dbbb=222 task3
string1: -Daaa=111 -Dbbb=222
string2: task1 task2 task3
string1: -Daaa=111 -Dbbb=222
string2: task1 task2 task3
```