# How get next to next argument in linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have wrote simple shell script `test.sh` as follows:

```
while getopts ":A:" OPTION
do 
   case $OPTION in
   A)
      echo $OPTARG
   ?)
      echo "no option"

  esac
done
```

And executed the scripts as follows

```
$ ./test.sh -A 1 2
```

Now if got argument 1 by $OPTARG but how can i access the second argument ( 2 in this case)?

Regards
Jayesh

Comment: what is the question??

Comment: Can you elaborate in little more detail like what exactly you want to do with above script?

Comment: okay if I understand you correctly you are trying to bind both 1 and 2 with `-A` option, you can pass 2 with another switch like `./test.sh -A 1 -B 2` and then parse them. Here is a helpful link => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopt-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options.

(1) You can use `shift` and take `$1`

```
 while -n "$1"
 do  
  # do something with $1
  shift
 done
```

(2) You can iterate through the args:

```
 for i
 do
    # do something with $i
 done
```

There are other alternatives also.

Comment: Thanks lgor Chubin. it really help me.