# Access second argument in getopts option using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, getopts

Already asked question related this few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882482/how-get-next-to-next-argument-in-linux-shell-script)

But this time the condition different,Having following bash script using `getopts`

```
#!/bin/bash
ipaddr=""
sysip=""
msgType=""
sshTimeout=""
bulbIndex=""
bulbstate=""
while getopts ":ht:d:A:r:s:m:" OPTION
do
    case $OPTION in
        h)
            usage $LINENO
            ;;

        t)
            let "t_count += 1"
            ipaddr="${OPTARG}"
            echo -e $ipaddr
            ;;

        d)
            let "d_count += 1"
            echo "Not supported"
            exit 0
            ;;

        A)
            let "A_count += 1"
            bulbIndex="${OPTARG}"  #  After -A option firsr argument is bulb index and second is state off/on
            bulbstate=$3
            printf "Set %s state on %s bulb\n" $bulbstate $bulbIndex
            ;;

        r)
            let "r_count += 1"
            sysip="${OPTARG}"
            echo -e $sysip
            ;;

        m)
            let "m_count += 1"     #message type 1:text 2:number 3:Text&number
            msgType="${OPTARG}"
            echo -e $msgType
            ;;

        s)
            let "s_count += 1"
            sshTimeout="${OPTARG}"
            echo -e $sshTimeout
            ;;

        ?)
            echo -e "wrong command sysntax"
            exit 0
            ;; 
    esac
done
```

Above script working fine for all options except `-A` option.What is wrong with it let you know from below script execution steps

```
$ ./sample.bash -A 3 OFF
Set OFF state on 3 bulb
```

This is expected output but when i give multiple option then it behave wrong like

```
$ ./sample.bash -t 192.168.0.1 -r 192.169.0.33 -A 3 OFF
192.168.0.1
192.169.0.33
Set -r state on 3 bulb
```

Here i expect `OFF` instead `-r` and obviously it gives this output because this time it not `$3` but it `$7` but my problem is how i inform to script it's now `$7` not `$3`.

And

```
$ ./sample.bash -t 192.168.0.1 -A 3 OFF -r 192.169.0.33 -m 1
192.168.0.1
Set -A state on 3 bulb
```

this time after `-A` all options are discarded and again `-A` instead `OFF`

How can i correctly access both arguments after `-A` option in any sequence of `-A` options?

Also any one have query regarding question let me know and frankly speaking whatever solution of it means very simple or hard but currently i don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after playing with `OPTIND` have found the way to get it.Modified the `-A` option as follows in `getopts`

```
A)
    let "A_count += 1"
    let "index += $OPTIND" # where initial value of index is 2

    bulbstate=${!index}

    bulbIndex="${OPTARG}"

    printf "Set %s state on %s bulb\n" $bulbstate $bulbIndex

    ((OPTIND++))
    ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

getopts only accepts one argument per option. How about passing both arguments to -A inside quotes, and separating them later inside your case statement?

```
A)
    let "A_count += 1"
    bulbIndex=${OPTARG% O*}
    bulbstate=${OPTARG#* }
    printf "Set %s state on %s bulb\n" $bulbstate $bulbIndex
    ;;
```

Then calling using:

```
$ ./sample.bash -t 192.168.0.1 -r 192.169.0.33 -A "3 OFF"
```

Gives:

```
192.168.0.1
192.169.0.33
Set OFF state on 3 bulb
```

If you can't use the quotes, then if you can make sure that -A is the last option used, then you can use the OPTARG to get the number, then simply get the final argument separately.

```
A)
    let "A_count += 1"
    bulbIndex="${OPTARG}"
    bulbstate=${@: -1}
    printf "Set %s state on %s bulb\n" $bulbstate $bulbIndex
    ;;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, you are right but it must for me to use `-A 3 4` instead yours

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you saying that you should be able to use -A with any number of bulbIndex arguments? eg `-A 3 4 5 OFF` ?

Comment: Not, and my mistake in previous comment it's `-A 3 OFF` not `-A 3 4`   .must only two argument after `-A` option.

Comment: Added another way to do it - but it only works if -A is the last option used. As I said in the answer, getopts only accepts one argument for each option, so adding a second argument is by necessity a bit of a hack. Alternatively, how about having a second argument? eg -A for ON, -X for OFF or similar.

Comment: That is the way to do but must `-A` is last option and in my case it's not case. Also some playing `OPTIND` it may be possible to get it.on my side have still try to get it and Thanks friend for stick with my question to solve it.