# Wireshark giving error when try to use Time Shift tool

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I found a packet capture file online that I am trying to analyze in Wireshark. I want to change the time on the packets so that the first packet happens at 9am on July 3rd, 2017.

However, the time shift tool is giving me an error that my time is entered incorrectly (see image). I have been googling this but I haven't had much luck figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square brackets, `[]`, denote a string without spaces and should be removed from your date string like so:

[image]

Comment: More to the point, the square brackets represent *optional* components and the use of square brackets for this purpose is very common.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242493/linux-unix-man-page-syntax-conventions.  

In fact, the dialog should really illustrate the time format as `[YYYY-MM-DD] <hh:mm:ss>[.ddd]` with the angle brackets surrounding the `hh:mm:ss` part to indicate that it is mandatory.