# What does it mean to specify two blobs in `git rebase`?

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, manpage, user-manual

My question is in two parts.

## First part:  Two blobs in `git rebase`

I am familiar with `git rebase -i HEAD^n`, where `n` means the number of commits ago you wish to rebase onto.

But, I also sometimes see `git rebase -i <branch> HEAD`.  In that case - How does the added `<branch>` parameter make a difference?

## Second part:  man page for git rebase

So....I checked the man page, and I see the following:

[image: Man page synopsis for git rebase]

On that man page, I see `[<upstream> [<branch>]]`, which I think might answer my question to the first part.

But, the peculiar thing about this is that I know `<>` means mandatory parameter, and `[]` means optional parameter.  In `[<upstream> [<branch>]]`, I see a mandatory parameter inside of an optional parameter.  What does this mean?

Comment: `<>` does *not* mean mandatory parameter. Lack of brackets `[]` means that. `<>` just means "don't literally put the string that's inside of these, but substitute a value that makes sense in context".

Comment: `<parameter>` does *not* mean "mandatory parameter".  That simply means it's not a literal value -- that is, it's something for which you substitute a real value, like a branch name.  Mandatory parameters are not listed inside `[...]`.

Comment: hmmmm [this](http://www.tfug.org/helpdesk/general/man.html) source indicates that mandatory parameters are in ` <>`.  But, what you say makes more sense, given the context.  I assume that source is wrong?

Comment: "Blob" is the wrong term to use. I think you meant to say "ref"?

Comment: I thought that a "ref" was a type of ["blob"](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/the-git-object-model-starting-with-the-blob/), or am I further exposing my ignorance?

Answer (score 1):

> How does the added `<branch>` parameter make a difference?

It does because a rebase replays all commits between upstream and branch.

- `git rebase -i HEAD^n` means all commits between HEAD^n and the current branch HEAD
- `git rebase -i <branch> HEAD` (or `git rebase -i <branch>`) means all commits between `<branch> HEAD` (which is here the upstream branch) and the current branch `HEAD`. For example: `git rebase -i origin/master HEAD`: all commits not yet pushed.

`[<upstream> [<branch>]]` means [both parameters are optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21503966/6309).
Since git has been created by the author of Linux, see [man-pages - conventions for writing Linux man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/man-pages.7.html)

> Brackets (`[]`) surround optional arguments

For `git rebase`, those optional parameters are:

> If `<branch>` is specified, `git rebase` will perform an automatic `git checkout <branch>` before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.
>
> If `<upstream>` is not specified, the upstream configured in `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` options will be used.
> The current branch is reset to `<upstream>`. This has the exact same effect as `git reset --hard <upstream>`.

Regarding `<...>` convention, see for instance "[Utility Argument Syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html)":

> **names of parameters that require substitution by actual values** are shown as follow:

```
<parameter name>
```

> The angle brackets are used for the symbolic grouping of a phrase representing a single parameter and conforming applications shall not include them in data submitted to the utility.

Finally, a ref is not a type of blob.
A ref is (see "[Git Internals - Git References](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References)") a reference to a SHA1 value.
A blob represents a content stored in a git repo. See "[Git Internals - Git Objects - Object storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Object-Storage)".

Comment: This is awesome.  Okay so, "`branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` options will be used" - I saw this in the man page too.  But, I checked out `git-config(1)`, like it says to, and I couldn't find anything on it.  I also couldn't find it in the `config` file in the directory `.git`.  Hints on where to find that?

Comment: @Hunle If you cannot find the config in the .git, it simply means there is no local config yet for that repo. Those two configs are set when a local branch has an upstream branch. See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch: "When a local branch is started off a remote-tracking branch, Git sets up the branch (specifically the `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge` configuration entries) so that `git pull` will appropriately merge from the remote-tracking branch."

Comment: I guess part of my confusion here stems from the fact that `HEAD` seems to be able to refer to both a `commit`, and a `branch`.  It seems to point to a `commit` first, and then, if required, can provide the branch upon which that commit resides.  Is that true?

Comment: @Hunle HEAD is "current commit" everywhere in git. See my old answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309, and the one above that old answer.