# Unset IFS value for shell script

Tags: shell, ksh, aix, ifs

In my use case I would like to change the value of `IFS` to a known separator (`-`). I tried the following:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS='-'
for x in $*
do
    echo $x
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

When using e.g. `-a b -c d` as input string I expect the output to be

```
a b
c d
```

However, what I get is

```
a
b
c
d
```

I'm on `AIX`.

Comment: Make sure you pass one argument to your shell script. `./foo "-a b -c d"` should produce the result you want

Comment: Your expected result is wrong, this would return an empty line, followed by `a b ` followed by `c d`. If you remove the whitespaces from `IFS` they will not be used as separators resulting in an empty first token and a trailing space in the second token.

Comment: Yes No problem for the empty line i just want to return an atomic token `a b` @AdrianFrühwirth

Comment: @Aymanadou But `a b` != `a b `.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your "observed" behaviour on AIX 6.1.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth actually in my usecase `a` is a parameter and `b` is the value of this parameter, so as a first step i want to tokenize my argument list to get parm|value in one token(no problem with trailing white spaces ...) in a second step i will split this token in parms and value

Comment: @DevSolar i have the same version 6.1 and i always reproduce

Comment: @Aymanadou Oh...please don't bake your own arguments parser, use [`getopts`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16496491/612462) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and I get

```
a b
c d
```

Try this

```
$ cat >a <<.
#!/bin/sh
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS='-'
for x in $*
do
    echo $x
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
.
$ chmod +x a
$ ./a "-a b -c d"

a b
c d
$
```

Comment: I am in AIX envirement and i get the bad result.

Comment: And what shell you are using ?

Comment: What shell are you using for launching your shell script, and what shell are you using for running your shell script (what is after the shebang) (these can be different)

Comment: i tried  #!/bin/ksh and #!/bin/sh both of themm gave the same bad result

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of getting this output using `awk` and avoid all the `IFS` manipulation:

```
s='-a b -c d'
echo "$s" | awk -F ' *- *' '{print $2 RS $3}'
a b
c d
```