# How do I control the user defined commands when executing a shell script in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am creating a shell script which has its own commands (or options). In simpler terms, my command line for executing the script is (in the terminal): `./myscript.sh -o:1,2,3,4` or `./myscript.sh -e:2,3,4`. Here is what the code (for the option part) looks like so far:

myscript.sh

```
for i
do
  case "$i" in
    "-o:"*|"--only:"*)
        # check if 1 is not included (if it is then exit)
        ;;

    "-e:"*|"--except:"*)
        # check if 1 is excluded (if it is then exit)
        ;;

    *)
      echo -e "invalid option\nTry './audit.sh --help' for help"
      exit
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Explanation:

The purpose of this code is to sum up all the values that the user passes through the `./myscript.sh -o:1,2,3,4` or subtract the values `./myscript.sh -e:2,3,4`. The `o` is the "only" option which adds up only the numbers passed to the script from this option. The `e` is the "exclude" option which excludes the values the user defines and subtracts those from 100.

I have a restriction that the number 1 must always be there (whether adding or subtracting). So I can't exclude the number 1. Here are some examples of illegal user input commands (`./myscript.sh -e:1,2,3,4`) and (`./myscript.sh -o:2,3,4`).

How do i check if the number 1 is always included in the `only` option and that the number 1 is not excluded from the `exclude` option? Thanks.

EDIT: The method I want to approach is using `awk`. Any suggestions?

Comment: well, you will want to do stuff like:  check to see if %2 is "-o" and then if it is, assign %2+1 to the variable.

Comment: you could also make other files which will handle this processing instead of running it purely in shell.  Its entirely up to you how you were wanting to do it.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Thanks for your help. I will add the method I want to use in the question

Comment: Have you considered using `getopts`? See http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash and stuff the Nets.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the value to check
2. Add commas to the front and end
3. Check of `,1,` is a substring

Implementation:

```
i="--only:3,4,5"

value=${i#*:}           # Strip prefix up to colon

if [[ ,$value, == *,1,* ]]  # Check if ,1, is a substring
then
  echo "You have a 1 in your list."
else
  echo "You're missing 1"
  exit 1
fi
```

To invert the check for checking exclusion, you can use `!=`.