# How to use the case command inside of a getopts while loop, UNIX

Tags: bash, unix

I currently have a Unix program where I'm trying to correctly use a getopts while loop with a case command nested inside. Inside that getopts while loop is a case command and inside the case case is two options that both are until loops. Here is the current code:

```
while getopts ufn: user
do

    case "$user"

    in

            u)

                    tty=$(who | grep "$user " | cut -d\  -f 2)
                    until who | grep "$user "  > /dev/null
                    do
                            sleep 60
                    done
                            echo "$user has logged onto $tty";;
            f)

                    until find | home/students/shaunkolkman/$user
                    do
                            test -d $user || test -f $user
                            sleep 20
                    done
                            echo "$user is a file or directory";;

    esac

done

user=$1
```

Option u is a until loop that looks for someone to log on and show what tty that user is on. Option f is a until loop finding either a file or directory. The until loops work perfectly fine. Option n will be added later once I figure out this problem.

Here's a example snipppet with a description of what is going on.

```
./mon4 -f vex
```

The issue I'm facing is that the f from -f is being seen as the variable. Along with -f still being read as a option from getopts. I don't understand why vex isn't read as the variable.

Comment: The option string needs a colon after the `f`, indicating that the option accepts a value.

Comment: eg: `while getopts u:f:n: ...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash

Comment: Sadly, these comments and answers aren't working for my code. putting the colons in their correct spots hasn't changed the issue. Either I'm not seeing the correct syntax or something else is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, options that require a value need a colon

```
while getopts uf:n: user
#               ^
#              /
#    notice ---
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/92de90e/ff-remux.sh#L63-L72)