# Bash script with argument that makes file executable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to make a bash script that checks if the file or directory exists,then if the file does,it checks the executable permission.I need to modify the script to be able to give a file executable permissions from an argument.

Example: Console input `./exist.sh +x file_name` should make the file executable.

This is the unfinished code that checks if the file/directory exists and if the file is executable or not. I need to add the `chmod` argument part.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
if [ -x $file ]; then
    echo "The file '$file' exists and it is exxecutable"

else
    echo "The file '$file' is not executable (or does not exist)"

fi

if [ -d $file ]; then
    echo "There is a directory named '$file'"

else
    echo "There is no directory named '$file'"

fi
```

Comment: It just checks if the file is executable. I need it to be able to change the permission.

Comment: Do you know how to change permissions of a file?

Comment: So add a `chmod` command, what's the problem?

Comment: Yo *do* know about the [`chmod`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html) command?

Comment: Yes I know to use chmod +x file_name but I don't know how to implement it in the script :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have optional arguments to your script, you need to check for them first.

In the case of just a couple of simple arguments, it would be simpler to check for them explicitly.

```
MAKEEXECUTABLE=0
while [ "${1:0:1}" = "+" ]; do
  case $1 in
     "+x")
         MAKEEXECUTABLE=1
        shift
        ;;
     *)
        echo "Unknown option '$1'"
        exit
   esac
done
file=$1
```

Then after you have determined that the file is not executable

```
if [ $MAKEEXECUTABLE -eq 1 ]; then
   chmod +x $file
fi
```

Should you decide to add more complex options, you may want to use something like `getops`:[example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)

Comment: Or just use `$1` as the argument to `chmod` directly if it is the change you want to make to the file and you've asserted that it is a safe/correct mode already.

Answer (score 1):

Add chmod something like:

```
if [ ! -x "$file" ]; then
   chmod +x $file
fi
```

This means if file does not have execute persmission, then add execute permission for the user.

Comment: Yes I know. But I am supposed to give the chmod permission from the terminal when executing the script. Ex: ./exist.sh +x file_name

Comment: Or viceversa ./exist.sh -x file_name

Comment: Then try: `chmod +x file_name; ./exist.sh` .. by writing -x after ./exist.sh you are trying to pass parameter to shell script and its not going to change the permission of your script.