# Bash script has several parameters always have random order how to put them in correct order always

Tags: bash, shell

My script is called by a program that generates argument randomly such as

```
input=12 output=14 destinationroute=10.0.0.0
```

and then calls my script with the generated arguments:

```
./getroute.sh input=12 output=14 destinationroute=10.0.0.0
```

Inside the script is like:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 input=$1
 output=$2
 destinationroute=$3
 ...
```

The program always calls arguments in random order (ex. input=12 output=14 or output=14 input=12), and I can't change the program.

Is there any way to recognize the correct parameters and put them in their proper place.

Comment: Are you asking about how to parse arguments instead of just assuming an order? Does your script currently handle the arguments in a specific order somehow?

Comment: I can't understand what you need, plz give some more details (ie., upload a code, your current problem and your required format)

Comment: Is this [tag:bash] or [tag:powershell]? Veeeery different tags.

Comment: Yes, it handles in specific order but automation software gives my script random order arguments, so how can i get specific argument to correct variable

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash

Comment: @jmajnert, `foo=bar` isn't exactly the argument format getopts expects.

Comment: @Charles Duffy - right! My bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't rely on order if they aren't in order. Just iterate over the arguments, look at which patterns they match, and assign to a variable appropriately:

```
for arg; do # default for a for loop is to iterate over "$@"
  case $arg in
    'input='*) input=${arg#*=} ;;
    'output='*) output=${arg#*=} ;;
    'destinationroute='*) destinationroute=${arg#*=} ;;
  esac
done
```

If, for some reason, you *really* wanted to update `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`, though, you can do that by putting the following code after the above loop:

```
set -- "$input" "$output" "$destinationroute"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call your function differently; For exmple:

```
./getroute.sh -i 12 -o 14 -d 10.0.0.0
```

Then inside your script use `getopt` to read the variables.

**Edit:**

My scripting knowledge is not strong; therefore, there should be a better way to do it.

As you don't have access to the Program, you can add some lines inside your script to get the inputs; for example:

```
input=`echo $* | grep -E -o "input=[0-9]{2}" | awk -F"=" {'print$2'}`
```

You can do the same thing for other variables.

Comment: The problem is my automation software puts equal to like input=12, output=14, so i was thinking if we can somehow read those input= and try to parse only values

Comment: So to clarify: your **Software** gives you a string like (input=12 output=.....) (lets call it **Str1**), and then calls your **Script** like `(./script $str1)`, and you don't have any control over the **Software** (to change the sequence of **Str1**. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes i dont have any control over automation software, i need to do it through script that my scripts correctly reads arguments

Comment: `grep | awk` is always silly: `awk -F= '/input=[[:digit:]]+/ {print $2}'` does the work of both tools in this case, as awk's capabilities are a proper superset of grep's. But in this case it's also silly because the shell can do everything needed built-in, without any fork/exec overhead from calling external commands.

Comment: Another thing to note: `./yourprog input="foo bar" output=baz` is distinct from `./yourprog input=foo bar output=baz`, but concatenating the arguments together with `$*` throws away the information distinguishing them.