# Shell or Bash script for selecting multiple options

Tags: bash, shell, unix, jenkins, scripting

I am looking to implement a shell script that will have the capability to push the image to multiple targets and multiple envs. The script should be parameterized to select any target and any env. Can you please suggest some tips for me to begin.

I am new to scripting and haven't done only a few. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I am planning to implement this in Jenkins. So if there is a better workaround than a script feel free to comment.

Thanks,
Manny

Comment: could you give more details? what images? what do you mean by push? deploy or just copy? what are the targets, envs? and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, then what you need to use is getopts in bash. Here is a [great answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)