# bash getopts not recognizing the second argument

Tags: bash, getopts

This is my entire script in its simplest form.

```
#!/bin/bash
src=""
targ=${PWD}

while getopts "s:t:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    s)
      src=$OPTARG
      ;;
    t)
      targ=$OPTARG
      ;;
  esac
  shift $((OPTIND-1))
done

echo "Source: $src"
echo "Target: $targ"
```

I run this script as `getopts_test -s a -t b`

However, it always prints the `pwd` in front of the `Target:` and never `b`

What am I missing here?

Comment: probably this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash

Comment: try taking the `shift` out of the while loop: move it to after `done`

Comment: When you do the shift inside the loop, you remove the `-s` and `a` arguments from the argument list, but `getopts` still thinks it processed arguments 1 and 2 (which now contain `-t` and `b`), so it looks beyond them and says "nothing else to do".

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the detailed explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for why `b` is never printed is that the `shift` within the loop moves the processed options away after the first iteration, i.e. after `a` has been printed. Use of `shift $((OPTIND-1))` is intended to access the possible given variadic parameters. Naturally, once you remove `shift`, `targ` gets reassigned to `b`, and `${PWD}` is no longer included in it since you don't have concatenation of the strings (`targ` and the option of `-t`) anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to what @glenn-jackman suggested in his comment
would be this :

```
#!/bin/bash
src=""
targ=${PWD}

while getopts "s:t:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    s)
      src=$OPTARG
      echo "Source: $src"
      ;;
    t)
      targ=$OPTARG
      echo "Target: $targ"
      ;;
  esac

done

shift $((OPTIND-1)) # Turning to non-option arguments say a file name and so on.
```

Here you go with the natural flow of arguments without `shift`ing.

Comment: The shift is needed after the loop so that you can remove the option arguments (and `--`) and leave `"$@"` with just the non-option arguments.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thankyou for reminding about the non-option args. Edited the answer. :)