# proper way to handle corner cases of parsing command line arguments using case command

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which accepts three command line arguments, e.g script is executed like this: `script -c <value> -h <value> -w <value>`. I would like to ensure that:

- order of arguments is not important
- if argument does not have a value, then error message is printed
- if any of the arguments are missing, then error message is printed
- if there are unknown arguments, then error message is printed

I accomplished this with following `case` statements:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
  case "$1" in
    -h)
      [[ x${2%%-*} != x ]] || { echo "Value for "$1" missing!"; exit 1; }
      host="$2"
      shift 2
    ;;
    -w)
      [[ x${2%%-*} != x ]] || { echo "Value for "$1" missing!"; exit 1; }
      warning="$2"
      shift 2
    ;;
    -c)
      [[ x${2%%-*} != x ]] || { echo "Value for "$1" missing!"; exit 1; }
      critical="$2"
      shift 2
    ;;
    "")
      [[ $host && $warning && $critical ]] || { echo "One of the arguments is missing!"; exit 1; }
      break
    ;;
    *)
      echo "Unknow option"
      exit 1
    ;;
  esac
done
```

However, maybe `case` itself has some advanced options which could avoid all those `[[ ]]` tests? Or maybe I should use another method altogether for processing command line arguments if I want to make sure that corner cases described above are also covered?

Comment: Usually things like these are checked by [getopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopt.1.html)

Comment: See examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 035](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) and the page linked from the very bottom too.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally use the `getopts` builtin for this, though there are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash) as well.  Getopts is the most portable and legible option, handling all of your "corner cases" pretty much automatically.

```
while getopts c:h:w: arg; do
  case $arg in
    ( c )  critical="$OPTARG" ;;
    ( h )  host="$OPTARG" ;;
    ( w )  warning="$OPTARG" ;;
    ( \? ) exit 2 ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "$critical" ] || [ -z "$host" ] || [ -z "$warning" ]; then
  echo "One of the arguments is missing!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Each option is followed by a colon, which indicates it has a mandatory argument.  If you have a flag that does not use an argument, do not follow the option with a colon.  POSIX `getopts` does not support options with optional arguments.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options/28466267#28466267) to this question about [supporting long options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options), which merely keys on the `-` option whose argument is parsed by a nested `case` switch.  Long options implemented in this manner can actually support optional arguments.

I'm a big fan of overloading `-h` for help.  Assuming you have a help function, put this before the `getopts` loop:

```
# when the sole argument is -h, provide help
if [ "$*" = "-h" ]; then
  help
  exit 0
fi
```