# How to use ${OPTARG} on getopts?

Tags: linux, bash, getopts

I have the following code:

```
while getopts ":p:t:n:" o; do
case "${o}" in
    p)
        p=${OPTARG}
        numep=$p
        mkdir $numep
        ;;
    t)
        t=${OPTARG}
        tip=$t
        if [ $tip == "c" ]; then
            touch $numep/$numep.c
            touch $numep/$numep.h
        elif [ $tip == "c++" ]; then
            touch $numep/$numep.cpp
            touch $numep/$numep.h
        fi
            ;;
        n)
            n=${OPTARG}
            nrFis=$n
            if [ $tip == "c" ]; then
                for i in $(seq $n); do
                    touch $numep/src/$numep$i.c
                    touch $numep/inc/$numep$i.h
                done
            elif [ $tip == "c++" ]; then
                for i in $(seq $n); do
                    touch $numep/src/$numep$i.cpp
                    touch $numep/inc/$numep$i.h
                done
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            err-help
            ;;
        esac
    done
```

err-help is a previously defined function that delivers instructions for a correct call.

A correct call of the script looks like this: `./script.sh -p project_name -t project_type -n source_files_number`

What am I trying to do: create a directory with a specific number of source files for a c or a c++ project.

My questions here: How do I have to use the ${OPTARG} ? What exactly does the p=${OPTARG} thing? Will the p, t, n variables fill with the right content?
How am I doing this right, please? :(

Comment: [There](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) [exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash) [many](http://tuxtweaks.com/2014/05/bash-getopts/) [tutorials](http://www.bahmanm.com/blogs/command-line-options-how-to-parse-in-bash-using-getopt) [about](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) getopts. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Like I said. I analyzed many tutorials and this is what I could write after.
If i write for every case p=${OPTARG} , t=${OPTARG}, n=${OPTARG}. Will those variables contain the right data? Or all will have the same content? I dont know the trick here...

Comment: Yes, they'll contain the right data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `getopts` correctly, but you are making assumptions about what order you're going to see the options. More on this later.

Let's look at a couple of excerpts from `help getopts`

> OPTSTRING contains the option letters to be recognized; **if a letter
> is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument**,
> which should be separated from it by white space.

> ...  When an option requires an argument,
> **getopts places that argument into the shell variable OPTARG**.

This is the magic of getopts. Since you added `p:` into your optstring, when `$o` = "p", the variable `$OPTARG` will contain whatever you provided to `-p`, in this case the string "project_name".

Now for some code review:

```
case "${o}" in
    p)
        p=${OPTARG}
        numep=$p
        mkdir $numep
        ;;
```

You only need to use braces if you are using arrays, or you need so disambiguate the variable name from the surrounding text (`$o_x` vs `${o}_x`) It would be tidier to write

```
case "$o" in ...
```

You don't need to create a special variable with the same name as the option. You never use `$p`. You can just write

```
numep="$OPTARG"
```

Always quote your variables. Always. Unless you specifically know when to leave them unquoted. If I provide `-p "some dir with spaces"`, then `mkdir $numep` will create **4** directories. You need to write

```
mkdir "$numep"
```

If the $numep directory already exists, you'll get an error message. If you don't want that, use `mkdir -p "$numep"` (see `man mkdir`)

Now, to address my first concern: there's nothing wrong with invoking your script and providing the options in *any order*

```
./script.sh -t project_type -n source_files_number -p project_name
```

Your option parsing assumes, in the `t` and `n` branches, that you've already set $numep, so you're assuming that the user provided `-p` *first*. If `-t` comes first, then $numep is empty, and you will attempt to create the file `/.h`. Even if you have permission to write to the root directory, this is not what you want to do. Parse **all** your options before you start doing stuff.

I would write this:

```
while getopts ":p:t:n:" o; do
    case "$o" in
        p)  numep="$OPTARG" ;;
        t)  case "$OPTARG" in
                c)  ext="c" ;;
                "c++")  ext="cpp" ;;
                *)  echo "Error: use 'c' or 'c++' for -t option" >&2
                    exit 1
                    ;;
            esac
            ;;
        n)  nrFis="$OPTARG" ;;
        *)  err-help ;;
    esac
done

mkdir -p "$numep"
touch "$numep/$numep.$ext"
touch "$numep/$numep.h"
for ((i=1; i<=$nrFis; i++)); do
    touch "$numep/src/$numep$i.$ext"
    touch "$numep/inc/$numep$i.h"
done
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about the order of the -p -t -n thing.
I will pass throw your code later and return with my questions or results.
Thank you for your time, glenn! :)