# In unix, How do I use the parameter removing method to get rid of a character and a space in front and behind it

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Let's say i have a string

```
r="part1 - part2"
```

i can do

```
PART1=${r%%-*}
PART2=${r##*-}
```

to get each part.
PART1 will also get the white space in front of it and PART2 will get the white space behind it.

However, since I am trying to use these two varibles as part of the path and it will become a problem since there is a space in it.

So is there a way to use the exact same method to escape the white space so it will also remove the white space behind/after it?

Comment: What you have written won't work as you need to match to the end or start of the string. Try `${r%%-*}` and `${r##*-}`

Comment: I do have the * sign, for some reason, stack overflow hides the sign, when I edit my question, it is there.

Comment: You can just include the space in the match `${r%% -*}`

Comment: Thank you!I will pay attention next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *split* a string based on a hyphen as a separator you can do this:

```
IFS=- read first second <<< "$r"
$ printf '%q\n' "$first"
part1\ # Note the space here
$ printf '%q\n' "$second"
\ part2
```

If you want to get only the *words* in a string you can do this:

```
$ read first separator second <<< "$r"
$ printf '%q\n' "$first"
part1
$ printf '%q\n' "$separator"
-
$ printf '%q\n' "$second"
part2
```

That said, spaces (and other special characters such as high Unicode, newlines, punctuation etc.) in file paths is a particularly thorny subject for shell programming, but they are perfectly valid. The first rule of handling special paths is **[quoting properly](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).** Once you get that right, you're 90% of the way towards supporting basically *any* valid *nix path. The other 10% involve various tricks like using `--` as a separator between arguments and paths if you need to [parse arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16496491/96588), starting relative paths with `./` outside scripts and [`"$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE\[0\]}")" && pwd)"` inside scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/96588), [looping over paths using `while`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and escaping special characters using `$''` quotes (see `man bash`). I would definitely recommend learning these and writing **test cases** for your script with incrementally more complex file names to guarantee that it works.

Comment: I think they just want to remove the spaces.

Comment: So i have a shell script. I have to split a filename into two variables. But the filename contains both hyphen and space. Such as "first - second". Using my old meta, I will get "first " with space after it  and " second" with space in front of the word. Now I need to use these two varibles in such way that I will move a file to a folder named as the first variable and rename the file as a second variable.so I would do mv "file" "Part1/Part2" since it has space in it, it throw me off. I got "mv cannot move 'testFile - TestDir.txt' to ''testFile / TestDir.txt' : No such file or directory.

Comment: I have noticed that the part where it says 'testFile / TestDir.txt' has a space in front and after the slash. So i was thinking i didn't handle the space in the variable.

Comment: My script so hard, only handles a file name without space. So "testFile-TestDir.txt" will work, but "testFile - TestDir.txt" won't work

Comment: Thanks, i got it, i was over-complicating the problem!