# Script to act on multiple files in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a script that can be given 3 arguments: task, infile-type, outfile-type; and it should apply the task to each of such files in the folder. For example, I should be able to give command: `convert png jpg`, and it should convert all png files to jpg in the folder. I should also be able to send options with task, enclosed in quotes, e.g.: `"convert -o myoption" png jpg`

I tried:

```
#! /bin/bash
for f in *.$2
  do 
    $1 "$f" -o "${f%.$2}.$3"
  done
```

Will above work or do I need to enclose $1 etc in {} or []? I have not tried it since, if erroneous, it may cause unpredictable damage to files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: this might help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question but it seems you need to use **getopt** or **getopts**. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Comment: Thanks everyone for your very useful answers. I am trying these and will post the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the command to the end of your argument list.

```
#! /bin/bash
src=$1; shift
dst=$1; shift
for f in *."$src"
do 
  "$@" "$f" -s -o "${f%.$src}.$dst"
done
```

Then the arguments get correctly quoted

```
my-script png jpg convert -o myoption
```

even, if the arguments contain spaces.

```
my-script png jpg convert --some-option "argument with spacees"
```

Comment: It should be `dst=$1` and not $2 (since shift has been used). Otherwise it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can express that quite readily with **GNU Parallel** and have the added benefit of all the tasks being run in parallel too:

```
parallel convert {} {.}.png ::: *.jpg
```

where `{}` replaces the argument and `{.}` represents the argument without extension.

As regards your concern for doing something potentially dangerous, use `--dry-run` to test out what it would do, without actually doing anything:

```
parallel --dry-run convert -o XYZ {} {.}.png ::: *.jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
convert -o XYZ a.jpg a.png
convert -o XYZ a\ g.jpg a\ g.png
convert -o XYZ b.jpg b.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to have a list of files in your folder. You may try that. Let me now if there are some errors so I may can change it to what you exactly want

```
#! /bin/bash

# Command which should performed
echo $1
# File type IN
echo $2
# File type OUT
echo $3

for i in $(ls)
do

    $1 $2 $3 $i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

An useful technique while writing shell scripts that may have dangerous results
simply consists in using the `echo` builtin.

Your code is substantially correct, I'd just use a bit of extra quoting
and a test to exclude the possibility of action on non existing files (even if this is more cosmetic...)

```
repeat() { for f in *.$2 ; do
    [ -f "$f" ] && echo $1 \"$f\" \"${f%.$2}.$3\"
  done ; }
```

Here it is a short terminal session to show how it works

```
$ ls
a b.png  a.png  b.png
$ repeat() { for f in *.$2 ; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo $1 \"$f\" \"${f%.$2}.$3\" ; done ; }
$ repeat 'cp -f' pmg jpg     #### typinh error
$ repeat 'cp -f' png jpg
cp -f "a b.png" "a b.jpg"
cp -f "a.png" "a.jpg"
cp -f "b.png" "b.jpg"
$ repeat 'cp -f' png jpg | sh
$ ls
a b.jpg  a b.png  a.jpg  a.png  b.jpg  b.png
$
```

When you are 99.9% sure of your code, remove the `echo` and there you are...