# How to echo when there is no input in getopts command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, getopts

This is put before the case statements. It still outputs nothing when executed without any input.

```
 while getopts :x:y:z: OPT; do
 if [ $OPT == "" ]; then
 echo "Null"
 exit 10
 fi
```

also, how should I code this to execute the values in any position/order?
such as:

```
 .\project -x 120 -y 170 -z Car
 .\project -y 170 -z Car -x 120
```

Comment: This might help: [An example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16483119/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus Yes thank you I have seen it before. I am just a beginner, I still can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first test if no arguments were passed at all and exit (this happens before the getopts loop):

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  usage # Call usage function or echo some usage message
  exit 
fi
```

There's no way of forcing mandatory arguments. What you can do is test for a certain value after the getopts loop has finished.
If `-x` is a mandatory option, and it is used to set the `var` variable,  test to see if it hasn't been set by the getopts loop, and if so print a relevant message and exit:

```
if [ -z ${var+x} ]; then
 echo "No -x argument supplied. exiting"
 exit 10
fi
```

The above runs after the case statement.

Also, you're missing a 'done' after your while loop, most likely a typo.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working now! Can you also help me how to input these values in any order?

Comment: @Kim, As each argument is not dependent on the others, their order is arbitrary and can be changed freely.

Comment: OHH, I must have a typo before. Everything is fine now, thanks again!