# Which trigger the internal error?

Tags: bash, getopt

Edit the content of  mytest.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash    
ARGS=`getopt -o c`
eval set -- "${ARGS}"

while true;
do
    case "$1" in
        -c)
            echo "i am c"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Internal error!"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

`bash mytest.sh -c`  get the error info  `Internal error!` ,why can't trigger the info `i am c`?

Comment: Have you tried `echo "$1"` to see what's in $1? (And then perhaps `echo "$2"` and so on...)

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: See: [An example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16483119/3776858)

Comment: May be you are using different implementation of getopt. I know that at-least there are BSD version and GNU version.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash    
ARGS=$(getopt -o c -- "$@")
eval set -- "${ARGS}"

while true;
do
    case "$1" in
        -c)
            echo "i am c"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Internal error!"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

I really don't know what you intend to do. But the current code you have results in an infinite loop. Better thing would be: break from the while condition after the option is encountered.

Mostly likely a better thing to do:

```
#!/bin/bash    
ARGS=$(getopt -o c -- "$@")
eval set -- "${ARGS}"

while true;
do
    case "$1" in
        -c)
            echo "i am c"
            # do some processing.
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Internal error!"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Note: btw, prefer to use getopts instead of getopt