# Bash script with options to run another script

Tags: bash

I wish to create a simple bash script.

```
buildapp.sh -build1
buildapp.sh -build2 
etc
```

the option build1/2/3/ etc call an external script depending on option.

So something like

```
buildapp.sh -build1 → script1.sh
buildapp.sh -build2 → script2.sh
```

Comment: Kindly include more information. The question is not clear. Is it you are looking for a conditional statement like if, if else etc?

Comment: If you check the options you're passed, you can do whatever actions you'd like based on them.  What are you having trouble with so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
if [ "$1" = "-build1" ]; then
  path/to/script1.sh
elif [ "$1" = "-build2" ]; then
  path/to/script2.sh
elif [ "$1" = "-build3" ]; then
  path/to/script3.sh
else
  echo "Incorrect parameter"
fi
```

Another option is to use getops (see [An example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash))

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
#!/bin/bash
./script${1//[!0-9]/}.sh # './' is the path to scriptX.sh, you may need to adjust it
```

A very tiny solution, that works with every number, by simply referencing the numeric argument suffix. E.g. it calls `./script123.sh` with `-build123`.

**Solution (extended)**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ '-build' == "${1//[0-9]/}" ]]
then
  ./script${1//[!0-9]/}.sh
fi
```

Extends the above version, so that it only runs `./scriptXXX.sh`, if the argument prefix is `-build`

Comment: `-build10` and you have a problem :)

Comment: Oh yes! you're right. That's not optimal. The meaning of '-build' is ignored too. This solution has potential to be improved. :-)

Comment: If you want to do it like this, I recommend extracting the number with something like: `[[ $1 =~ ([0-9]+)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"` instead :)

Comment: Thanks you. That was a helpful hint.