# How do I correctly use getopt in a cshell script?

Tags: getopt, tcsh

## Problem

I am trying to make a chshell script that takes in user input from several options. Inspired by [this bash example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash), I tried to construct a [while loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392436/how-to-use-while-loop-in-csh-shell-command-prompt) and [switch case](http://parallel.vub.ac.be/documentation/linux/unixdoc_download/Scripts.html) statement pattern around the [`getopt`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) command.  After several iterations I have tried to interpret this [example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/getopt.htm) from IBM:

```
set argv=`getopt :a:b:c:d:e: $*`

if ($? != 0) then
    exit 1
endif
while ({ ` $1 != --` })
    switch ($1)
        case[-a]:
            yada
            breaksw
        case[-b]:
            yada
            breaksw
        case[-c]:
            yada
            breaksw
        case[-d]:
            yada
            breaksw
        case[-e]:
            yada
            breaksw           
        default:
            yada default
            breaksw
     ends
end
shift
```

It returns the error: `-a: Command not found`.

## Question

How do I correctly and efficiently use getopt in cshell **without** reinventing the wheel and essentially recopying the underlying getopt code?