# How do I port getopts logic from bash to cshell?

Tags: tcsh, getopts

## Background

In bash I have a working getopts interface as depicted below:

```
while getopts "a:b:c:d:" OPTION ; do
    case "$OPTION" in
        a) JET="$OPTARG" ;;
        b) FUEL="$OPTARG" ;;
        c) CAN="$OPTARG" ;;
        d) MELT="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) echo "Usage $0 -a A -b B -c C -d D"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

#Check out input parameters
for PARAM in JET FUEL CAN MELT; do
    echo "$PARAM in [${!PARAM}]"
done
```

## Question

What is the cshell translation for this?  I cannot find a clear example of [getopts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7mao/index.html) (with an s) in cshell, yet there is an [easily findable one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash) for bash.  This is distinct from [attempting to use getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56399485/how-do-i-correctly-use-getopt-in-a-cshell-script), since getopts is an entirely different function from [getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt).

Comment: Two sources state that getopts is not available for csh. https://www3.physnet.uni-hamburg.de/physnet/Tru64-Unix/HTML/MAN/MAN1/0221____.HTM
https://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html

Comment: "Easier to use and generally better than getopt, though of course not available in csh-like shells. You shouldn't be using those anyway."   Oof, that hit me right in kernel.