# how to pass arguments with flags in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to run the scripts as below. I want to set the flags to true but it doesnt work.

```
./test.sh ./api_service -s -i
```

if I run the scripts only with flags i am able to get the expected output. how to pass  arguments and flags to the script?

```
./test.sh -s -i
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_project_path="$1"
name=$(echo ${input_project_path} | cut -d"/" -f2)
echo $name

skiptests=false
install_libs=false

while getopts ":si" option; do
  case "${option}" in
    s )
        skiptests=true
        if [ "$skiptests" = true ] ; then
            echo "something....";
        else
            echo "test...";
        fi
        ;;
    i)
        install_libs=true
        ;;
    \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    :)
        echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done

echo $skiptests
echo $install_libs
```

Comment: Place a `shift` after `input_project_path="$1"`

Comment: I strongly advise you to read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035

Comment: thanks! adding shift works.

Comment: The normal convention is for flags to go *before* non-flag arguments, so it should be `./test.sh -s -i ./api_service`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set a value for a flag, then you need to make 2 changes:

- add `:` after the flag option in the `getopts` string
- Save the value using `$OPTARG`

For example, if you want to pass a value for flag `i`, but not `s` you'd do something like this:

```sh
while getopts ":si:" option; do
  case "${option}" in
    s )
        skiptests=true
        if [ "$skiptests" = true ] ; then
            echo "something....";
        else
            echo "test...";
        fi
        ;;
    i)
        install_libs=$OPTARG
        ;;
    ...
    esac
done
```

I used `...` to avoid copying the rest of your `case` statement.

Notice that:

- There is an extra `:` after the `i` option
- And in the `i`'s case statement, the value is set to `$OPTARG`'s value.
- There was no change made to the `s` case
- Also note the `options`' values come after the corresponding flags

See this thread [An example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash) for a more in depth explanation of `getopt`.