# Bash - Best way to have helpFunction & default parameter values

Tags: bash

After a lot of read, SO or others, I'm really wondering about the best / cleanest way to have a bash script with parameters, optionals with default values.

Here is my script for now:

```
#!/bin/bash

helpFunction()
{
   echo ""
   echo "Usage: $0 --reload --mode=[single|cluster]"
   echo -e  "\t--reload Reload the database : fixtures & schema"
   echo -e  "\t--mode Mode of build : single or cluster"
   exit 1
}

while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -h|--help) helpFunction; shift ;;
        -r|--reload) reload=true; shift ;;
        -m|--mode) mode="single"; shift ;;
        # ... (same format for other required arguments)
        *) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1" ;;
    esac
    shift
done

./bin/sh/tools/build.sh -e local -m $mode -p local
```

For now, the `$mode` variable seems to not be set if I don't set it, how can I have a default value for this variable ? (default is *single*)

What I want is the user to call the script like (reload is *true*, mode is *cluster*):

```
bin/script.sh -r --mode=cluster
```

Or by default (reload is *false*, mode is *single*):

```
bin/script.sh
```

Is this the good way to wait for parameters ? I read other ways, but no real explanations.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a line `mode="single"` near the top of your script, to make it the default.

Comment: @markp-fuso can you put as an answer for code formatting please ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal `best/cleanest` method; it eventually comes down to what works best for you; some ideas:

1. set `mode` to a default value before the `while/case` loop
2. after the `while/case` loop test `mode` and if unset/undefined then set to a
   default value (should probably play it safe and `unset mode` before the `while/case` loop though in this case you might as well see idea #1)
3. pass to `build.sh` wrapped in double quotes (ie, `build.sh -e local -m "$mode" -p local`) and have `build.sh` test for the `-m` argument being unset/undefined and set to a default value
4. a variation on #2 and #3 is to use parameter substitution when
   passing `mode` to `build.sh`, eg: `build.sh -e local -m "${mode:-default_value}" -p local`
5. if your script sources a config/ini file you could assign `mode` a
   default value in said config/ini file and then make sure said config/ini file is sourced before the `while/case` loop

Answer (score 2):

If you set the mode beforehand, that will be its default. If you want parameter with assignment, you need to grab `$2` and shift twice.

```sh
mode="single"
while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -h|--help) helpFunction; shift ;;
        -r|--reload) reload=true; shift ;;
        -m|--mode) mode="$2"; shift; shift ;;
        # ... (same format for other required arguments)
        *) echo "Unknown parameter passed: $1" ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

I think it's also good to restore the positional arguments. Since you may want to use them, but that depends on your script.

```sh
mode="single"
reload="false"

POSITIONAL=()
while [[ "$#" -gt 0 ]]; do
  case $1 in
  -h | --help)
    helpFunction
    shift
    ;;
  -r | --reload)
    reload=true
    shift
    ;;
  -m | --mode)
    mode="$2"
    shift
    shift
    ;;
  *)
    POSITIONAL+=("$1")
    shift
    ;;
  esac
done
set -- "${POSITIONAL[@]}"

COMMAND="$1"
```

Then you could invoke a function that is called like the `$COMMAND` and pass the rest of the params with `$@`, and shift again and set the subcommand to $1. You can do this infinitely to get a chain of (sub)commands.

You can still check if a valid command was provided before you try to call the `$COMMAND`.

```sh
COMMAND_LIST="add issue revoke"

case $COMMAND_LIST in
*"$COMMAND"*)
  "$COMMAND" "$@"
  ;;
*)
  helpFunction
  echo "ERROR: Unknown command: $COMMAND"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

But that is of course only if your script supports commands/subcommands. Otherwise, it makes sense to error right away like you did, if there is an unknown parameter.