# Wildcard getopt is not producing expected result

Tags: linux, sh

I want getopt to send my user to a help page if they don't supply an option. Goal: If the user specifies no command line or `-h`, set `flag_help` to 1.

```
flag_help=0
flag_test_user=0
flag_demo_user=1
flag_skip_initial_pause=0

while getopts 'hdts' flag; do
    case ${flag} in
        h)
            flag_help=1
            ;;
        d)
            echo "Using Demo Mode"
            flag_test_user=0
            flag_demo_user=1
            ;;
        t)
            echo "Using Test Mode"
            flag_test_user=1
            flag_demo_user=0
            ;;
        s)
            echo "Will skip initial pause.."
            flag_skip_initial_pause=1
            ;;
        *)
            flag_help=1
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "flag_help: $flag_help"
```

I then test it:

```
$ sh tools/setup-demo.sh
flag_help: 0
```

```
$ sh tools/setup-demo.sh  -h
flag_help: 1
```

I must have some oddball error in there, but I'm not sure what. To be safe, I did some research and there is a great example thread here:
[An example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)

My syntax seems correct based on that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: read the man page of getopt(1) command to see how to use it.  There are some examples and you are using it bad.

Answer (score 0):

> If the user specifies no command line or -h, set the flag_help to 1.

Detect that.

```
if (($# == 0)); then
    flag_help=1
fi
while getopt ......
    ...
done
```

Comment: Okay. I see my logic error. The *) is saying "for anything that does not match" not "for no command-line OR anything that does not match". WOW. Totally missed the obvious. Great catch, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to be compatible and not to tie to bash, I recommend you to use the *getopt(1)* command.  This way you will be compatible with any bourne shell and you will not depend on *bash(1)* internal command.

For reference, read the manual page of *getopt(1)*, to check how to use the *getopt(1)* command.

```
flag_help=1
flag_test_user=0
flag_demo_user=1
flag_skip_initial_pause=0

args=`getopt hdts $*`
set -- $args

while :; do
    case "$1" in
        -h)
            flag_help=1
            flag_test_user=0
            flag_demo_user=0
            shift
            ;;
        -d)
            echo "Using Demo Mode"
            flag_help=0
            flag_test_user=0
            flag_demo_user=1
            shift
            ;;
        -t)
            echo "Using Test Mode"
            flag_help=0
            flag_test_user=1
            flag_demo_user=0
            shift
            ;;
        -s)
            echo "Will skip initial pause.."
            flag_skip_initial_pause=1
            flag_help=0
            shift
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break;
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "flag_help: $flag_help"
echo nonopt args: "$@"
```

This way you will be compatible with any bourne shell  and not only *bash(1)*

If you want to use it with the `bash` `getopts` command, then:

```
flag_help=1
flag_test_user=0
flag_demo_user=1
flag_skip_initial_pause=0

while getopts 'hdts' flag $*; do
    case ${flag} in
        h)
            flag_help=1
            ;;
        d)
            echo "Using Demo Mode"
            flag_help=0
            flag_test_user=0
            flag_demo_user=1
            ;;
        t)
            echo "Using Test Mode"
            flag_help=0
            flag_test_user=1
            flag_demo_user=0
            ;;
        s)
            echo "Will skip initial pause.."
            flag_help=0
            flag_skip_initial_pause=1
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac
done

echo "flag_help: $flag_help"
```

Can be a possible solution to your problem.  It is better to  initially set `flag_help` to 1, and in case one of the options is selected, to set it at 0.