# Argument is empty using getopts

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to be able to run a script like `run.sh test -a` but my arguments are empty.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function install() {
    echo "Installing $1"
}

while getopts "ab" ARG; do
  case "$ARG" in
    a) install
       echo "Setting up A" ;;
    b) install
       echo "Setting up B" ;;
    *​) echo "argument missing" ;;
  esac
done
```

My expected output would be if I run `run.sh test -a`:

```
Installing test
Setting up A
```

However there is no output returned. If I run `run.sh -a`, I get:

```
Installing
Setting up A
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)

Comment: That is odd, the output should be `Installing` without anything after in both cases.

Comment: You don't pass any arguments to `install`, so $1 is empty.

Comment: You can't access the shell positional parameters from inside a function; the function's own positional parameters shadows them.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca The linked question confuses getopt (program) with getopts (builtin)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant way but I got it sort of working by using the second argument instead.

Ended up reworking it like so:

```
install=$2

function install() {
    echo "Installing $install"
}

while getopts "ab" ARG; do
  case "$ARG" in
    a) install
       echo "Setting up A" ;;
    b) install
       echo "Setting up B" ;;
    *​) echo "argument missing" ;;
  esac
done
```

So I running `run.sh -a test` would return:

```
Installing test
Setting up A
```

Answer (score 0):

`getopts` does not allow you to specify the options after the non-option arguments. This is a general principle of many Unix tools, though some have deviated.

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that Windows has persuaded some users that this is a good idea, which should immediately tell you that it's not.