# How can I add an argument for executable linux file

Tags: linux, bash, elf

I have a executable linux file called "Fyserver". I want to open it with this arg

```bash
./Fyserver --pass 2849
```

If I don't enter this `--pass` arg to ELF, then it should exit itself without even running. Is there a way to do this?

NOTE: I don't have the source code of this ELF. I want to do it in bash.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking for how to create an [alias](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+alias) so you can avoid typing out the entire command each time? Or did you want to create an icon you can click on in your file manager?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An example of how to use getopts in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash)

Comment: @Dúthomhas No. I want to add an password argument for some executable linux file. If the user runs the `./Fyserver` the executable linux file should exit itself. If the user runs the `./Fyserver --pass string`, it should run.

Comment: @m19v No It doesn't. I want to add `--pass` argument for some executable linux file (not bash script, and not mine).

Comment: _**Your question is unclear.**_ I have no idea what Fyserver is, or what `--pass NNNN` does, or what you expect to happen. If you are trying to modify an executable to do something it doesn’t do, then... that’s not how things work.

Comment: Is the new command argument supposed to modify the behavior of the program?

Comment: @Dúthomhas It's something like that. If the user runs this ELF without `--pass NNNN` argument, It shouldn't run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no sane way to do what you are asking. You can't add new behavior to a binary without access to the source code or some *serious* reverse engineering skills.

The usual solution is to create a simple wrapper, i.e. move `./Fyserver` to `./Fyserver.real` and create a script like

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$1" = "--pass" ] || { echo "Syntax: $0 --pass <pass>" >&2; exit 127; }
exec ./Fyserver.real "$@"
```

The argument checking could arguably be more sophisticated, but this should at least give you an idea of how this is usually handled.

If you really wanted to, I suppose you could write this logic in a compiled language, and embed the original binary within it somehow.

Comment: This answer only works when `./Fyserver.real` is in the current directory. The answer can be _trivially_ made better by using `exec "$0.real"` instead.

Comment: I originally wrote an instruction to move it somewhere like `/usr/local/bin/Fyserver.real` but the OP is specifically asking about running something in the current directory. But thanks, your suggestion is an improvement.