# How would I make my bash script non interactive?

Tags: bash, shell, console

Hi I am doing a project where I must write a bash script calculator that allows you to perform multiple arithmetic operations and also to the power of. I have done the basic bit but have been told I must make it non interactive and was just wondering how would I do this? My code has been provided below.

```
clear
bash
while [ -z "$arg1" ]
do
read -p "Enter argument1: " arg1
done

while [ -z "$arg2" ]
do
read -p "Enter argument2: " arg2
done

echo "You've entered: arg1=$arg1 and arg2=$arg2"

let "addition=arg1+arg2"
let "subtraction=arg1-arg2"
let "multiplication=arg1*arg2"
let "division=arg1 / arg2"
let "power=arg1**arg2"

echo -e "results:\n"
echo "$arg1+$arg2=$addition"
echo "$arg1-$arg2=$subtraction"
echo "$arg1*arg2=$multiplication"
echo "$arg1/$arg2=$division"
echo "$arg1^$arg2=$power"
```

I was thinking of trying to make it so that the user does not have to type in 2 numbers but I am still pretty new to bash and scripts as a whole so I am wondering how to do this.

Comment: Use the command line arguments instead of prompting for input. These are in `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: See [How can I pass a command line argument into a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31414/264812).

Comment: Also see [Handling positional parameters [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams).

Answer (score 1):

Use `getopts` to process arguments to your script. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16496491/3833426) from this site. You could replace the lines from your first line to your `echo "You've entered …"` with modified code from the other answer I linked to. You might want to read the PARAMETERS section of `man bash`, in particular understand what the Special Parameters are (*, @, #, ?, -, $, !, and 0). You should know those cold if you are scripting [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

An alternative is to use the builtin `read`. I would use `getopts`.