# How can a Bash function detect whether it is being used with positional or named arguments?

Tags: bash, function, parsing, position, named-parameters

I'm writing a Bash function that is to be capable of attempting to use either positional or named arguments, whereby positional arguments are accessed in the usual `"${1}"`, `"${2}"` way and named arguments are accessed using `getopts`. I have some example code and example usage shown below in order to illustrate what I'm trying to do. The problem is that the check I'm doing on the variable `${*}` is just a grep for the character `-`, which limits greatly the character content of further arguments. What would be a more intelligent or robust way of checking for named arguments in Bash?

example code:

```
function1(){
    # flags
        argumentsFlag1=""
            # n: named arguments
            # p: positional arguments
        verboseFlag1="0"
            # v: verbose
        silentFlag1="0"
            # 0: standard output
            # 1: no standard output
    # options and arguments
        # Determine if positional or named arguments are used.
            # If the arguments contain "-", then named arguments are assumed,
            # otherwise positional arguments are assumed.
                if [ "$(echo "${*}" | grep "-")" ]; then
                    argumentsFlag1="n"
                else
                   argumentsFlag1="p"
                fi
        # handle named arguments
            if [ "${argumentsFlag1}" == "n" ]; then
                OPTIND=1; while getopts "i:sv" options; do
                    case "${options}" in
                        i)
                            input1="${OPTARG}"
                            ;;
                        v)
                            verboseFlag1=1
                            ;;
                        s)
                            silentFlag1=0
                            ;;
                        \?)
                            echo "invalid option -"${OPTARG}""
                            return
                            ;;
                        :)
                            echo "option -"${OPTARG}" requires an argument"
                            return
                            ;;
                    esac
                done
        # handle positional arguments
            elif [ "${argumentsFlag1}" == "p" ]; then
                input1="${1}"
        fi
    # default values
        if [ -z "${verboseFlag1}" ]; then
            verboseFlag1=0
        fi
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if  [ "${argumentsFlag1}" == "n" ]; then
        echo "named arguments assumed"
    elif [ "${argumentsFlag1}" == "p" ]; then
        echo "positional arguments assumed"
    fi
    echo "input: "${input1}""
}
```

example usage:

```
$ function1 zappo
positional arguments assumed
input: zappo

$ function1 -i zappo
named arguments assumed
input: zappo
```

EDIT: Please note that I am not trying to use positional and named arguments *at the same time*. I am trying to get the function to have a state in which it is interpreting the arguments solely as positional or solely for interpretation by `getopts` as a mix of positional and named arguments. There are to be instances in which `getopts` is not used. Imagine the following idea...

I have a function that is used from one data type to another. This function has two modes:

## quick mode

This mode can be used in a manner such as the following:

```
function fileName1 fileName2
```

It converts one file to another using internal assumptions and measurements made autonomously.

## advanced mode

This mode can be used in a manner such as the following:

```
function -i fileName1 -o fileName2 -m -r 100 -v
```

There can be positional arguments used in this mode, but they must be placed after the `getopts` positional options and arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Use `getopts` to process any named arguments, shifting them off the stack as you do so. If any remain afterward, they are your positional arguments.

Comment: The key here: [shift](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shift) -- `shift $((OPTIND-1))`

Comment: I think you mean something such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13400237/1556092). It's a good idea, but I'm not trying to use named and positional arguments at the same time; I'm trying to switch the state of the function such that it is interpreting the arguments as either solely positional or completely/partly named. Imagine a function that is used to convert from one thing to another. The quick mode would employ positional arguments (```function fileName1 fileName2```) while the advanced mode would employ named arguments for other specifications such as resolution, verbosity etc.

Comment: So why would this solution not work?  It handles either or both.  Sounds like you're trying to make this more complicated than is necessary.