# How can I get filename and argument with getopts from Command

Tags: bash, getopts

Here is the code, I want to run this command

Getting the ***test.log*** input, then convert it to ***text*** type, then store it on the ***output.txt*** file

`./small.sh test.log -t text -o output.txt`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

usage() { echo "$0 usage:" && grep " .)\ #" $0; exit 0; }
[ $# -eq 0 ] && usage

parse()
{
        local file=$1
        local type=$2
        local output=$3

        echo "file: ${file}, type: ${type}, output: ${output}"
}

while getopts ":ht:o:" arg; do
  case $arg in
    t) # specify type.
      type=${OPTARG} ;;
    o) # specify directory.
      output=${OPTARG} ;;
    h | *) # Display help.
      usage
      exit 0
      ;;
  esac
done

shift $(( OPTIND - 1))
parse "${file}" "${type}" "${output}"
```

with this code i can only get filename when i put it in unsort order like this
`./small.sh -t text -o output.txt test.log`

Comment: the conventional order would be `./small.sh -t text -o output.txt test.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get filename and argument with getopts
>
> ```
> ./small.sh test.log -t text -o output.txt
> ```

It is not possible. `getopts` only supports positional arguments *after* option arguments.

You can:

- accept the limitation
- use something elsem, like GNU `getopt`.
- write your own option parsing code

Comment: Option 4: workaround the limitation https://stackoverflow.com/a/63421397/16780116