# Number of arguments in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I want to test the number of arguments passed to a Linux shell script. If the number of arguments is not `2` or `4`, it should print something. Unfortunately it does not work. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]] || [[ $# -ne 4 ]];
then
    echo "here";
fi
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking number of arguments bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/checking-number-of-arguments-bash-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace logical `OR` by logical `AND`, so :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 2 && $# -ne 4 ]]; then
   echo "here"
fi
```

In arithmetic form:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (($# != 2 && $# != 4)); then
   echo "here"
fi
```

As you can see, no need to use 2 `[[ ]]`

Answer (score 1):

Logic.

```
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]] && [[ $# -ne 4 ]]; then
  echo "here"
fi
```

Comment: It's `-ne` (not equal)

Comment: Also, the code posted by OP also has a problem: a value is always not 2 or not 4