# For loop for shell Variables

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, environment-variables

### Overview:

I am trying to code an error for a function that requires multiple arguments.

- example:

  `myfunction arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4`

If any of these arguments are null I want to trow the user a syntax error.

### Attempts:

Without writing the individual arguments I tried:

```
# Error Checking
for i in "{1.4}"
do
    # Check for null values of Bash variables:
    [[ -z $"$i" ]] && {
        printf "Syntax Error: Missing Operator see:\nmyfunction --help\n"
        exit
        }
done
```

-and-

```
# Error Checking
for i in ${1..4}
do
    # Check for null values of Bash variables:
    [[ -z $i ]] && {
        printf "Syntax Error: Missing Operator see:\nmyfunction --help\n"
        exit
        }
done
```

### Attempted syntax check:

[image]
[image]

### Question:

Is what I am trying to do possible with a for loop?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

### Edit:

Also tried the following before I started messing with quotes and dollar signs:

```
# Error Checking
for i in {1..4}
do
    [[ -z $"$i" ]] && {
        printf "Syntax Error: Missing Operator see:\nansi-color --help\n"
        exit
        }
done
```

Comment: Yes I tried that iteration, which is the correct iteration looking at how it works now and still no dice.

Comment: `for i`  it defaults to iterate through the parameter list.

Comment: Do you just need to check that there is number of arguments?

Comment: @CalebAdams yes if there is an error later I direct them to --help

Comment: @RobertJ try reading this post: [checking-number-of-arguments-bash-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/checking-number-of-arguments-bash-script). This post may also be helpful [how-to-check-if-there-are-no-parameters-provided-to-a-command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25945/how-to-check-if-there-are-no-parameters-provided-to-a-command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to tackle this:

```
die () { echo "$@" >&2; exit 1; }

myfn () {
        [[ $# == 4 ]] || die 'wrong number of args'

        for d in "$@"; do [[ $d ]] || die 'null arg'; done
}

myfn2 () {
        [[ $# == 4 ]] || die 'wrong number of args'

        for ((i = 1; i <= $#; i++)); do
                [[ ${!i} ]] || die 'null arg'
        done
}
```

The `"$@"` is probably more idiomatic.  The indirection with `!` is very handy though not common.

Answer (score 0):

Caleb Adams pointed out that I could try something like this:

```
# Error Checking
[[ $# != 4 ]] && {
    printf "Syntax Error: Missing Operator see:\n\tansi-color --help\n"
    exit
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use a bash array and then check its length:

```
  args=($*)
  echo ${#args[*]}
```

But you can do this:

`myfunc() { for i in {1..4}; do
    if [[ -z ${!i} ]]; then
        echo error at $i
        return -1
    fi
done
...do other stuff
}`

Comment: The array won't work if some of the arguments contain whitespace. Consider `myfunction "a b" c "" d`. The third argument is null, but your array has 4 elements.

Comment: Point taken. More embarrassingly, the Caleb Adams suggestion to use the <code>$#</code> operator obviates the need for the array. The whitespace issue is handled by the <code>for</code> loop, but not null arguments. For that, the best suggestion I've seen uses 'parameter expansion for an alternate value'