# How to know how many parameters is a bash script accepting. I dont have permission to view/edit the script

Tags: shell

I have a `bash` script wherein I have to provide parameters. But I don't know how many parameters to be supplied while executing the script.

I don't have permission to view/edit the script to know how many parameters the script is accepting.

Please let me know if there is any way to know how many parameters a script can accept without view/edit the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [checking number of arguments bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/checking-number-of-arguments-bash-script)

Comment: Just execute the script without any parameter. If the owner of script had carefully written the script then, the script would print the expected number of arguments it expects and possibly description of same.

Comment: If you can not view it ( no read permission) you are pretty much out of luck; as you can not execute it either

Comment: Try running `theScript --help` or `theScript -h`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try supplying a variable number of arguments and seeing which one will work. To generate a script that creates variable args you could hack up a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# will send upto 5 command line arguments
for i in `seq 5`
do
    # replace newlines with spaces
    j=`seq $i | tr '\n' ' '`
    echo foo $j
done
```

It will result in something like:

```
foo 1
foo 1 2 
foo 1 2 3 
foo 1 2 3 4 
foo 1 2 3 4 5
```

where 'foo' is the name of the program you need to run.
Note that method this may only work if the script does not require any command line switches.