# BASH - Throw usage warning if no command line parameter is passed as an argument

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26396892/4380130) for a question on counting number of parameters passed argument to a `BASH` script. I'm interested on the line `: ${1?"Usage: $0 ARGUMENT"}` where it throws warning if no parameter is given.

Now I would like to invoke a usage function `Usage` using `: ${1?"Usage: $0 ARGUMENT"}` but I do not know how to do it. I tried `: ${1?Usage}` and `BASH` throws an error on this line. Can some suggest how to invoke a function using this.

The sample script is as below,

```
#!/bin/bash

function Usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [-q] [-d]"
    echo ""
    echo "where:"
    echo "     -q: Query info"
    echo "     -d: delete info"
    echo ""
}

# Exit if no argument is passed in
: ${1?Usage}

while getopts "qd" opt; do
    case $opt in
        q)
            echo "Query info"
            ;;
        d)
            echo "Delete info"
            ;;
        *)
            Usage;
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: @hek2mgl, updated the question with pseudo code.

Comment: Why can't you handle this in `getopts` itself?, to which flag is this parameter meant for?

Comment: @Inian Having that either `q` or `d` is required, the check for $1 makes sense. AFAIK `getopts` has no facility to say `q` or `d` is required. However, we might set a variable inside `getopts` and check that afterwards. Added that to my answer.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't really take any *action* in the `while` loop; just record which options are present. *After* the while loop, you could print the usage message and exit if you have determined that no option were used. (Which, after reading more closely, is exactly what hek2mgl does in the latter half of his answer...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
function Usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [-q] [-d]"
    echo ""
    echo "where:"
    echo "     -q: Query info"
    echo "     -d: delete info"
    echo ""
}

# Exit if no argument is passed in
: ${1?"$(Usage)"}
```

Anyhow, I think this is more readable:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
    Usage
fi
```

---

Another idea would be to handle it like this:

```
mode=""
while getopts "qdh" opt; do
    case $opt in
        q)
            mode="Query info"
            ;;
        d)
            mode="Delete info"
            ;;
        h)
            Usage
            exit 0
            ;;
        *)
            Usage >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "${mode}" ] ; then
    Usage >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `getopts` will not print the usage info.

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for the input. I could use the `: ${1?"$(Usage)"}` for printing usage info but your second suggestion is more readable. I wanted to try this `: ${1?"$(Usage)"}` and see how that works since the syntax was new to me.

Comment: @Inian  Personally I would choose a different programming language in the moment when it comes to more complex command line arguments. But yes, you can also print the Usage info based on the results of `getopts`, you would even need to if you want to handle the arguments to options correctly instead of just checking the number of arguments. Again, I recommend [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html). :)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Appreciate it, `++` for demonstrating usage in the form, `${1?"$(Usage)"}` (not used before)

Comment: @Inian I would not recommend it, was just suggesting the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

you just need pass argument to the bash script.
assume that the bash script's name is `hello.sh`;
for example:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # script's name is hello.sh
    : ${1?"Usage: $0 Argument"}
    echo hello,$1
```

then `chmod a+x hello.sh`

then we call the script use this :
`bash hello.sh yourname`
then echo the "hello,yourname"
if you just called use `bash hello.sh` and no argument for this script 
you will get your error message like this `Usage: hello.sh Argument`

[image]