# Bash shell programs

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a version of file copy that allows the user to append the target file that already exists. The program takes two arguments: source-file and destination-file.

If the destination-file already exists, it must ask the user to choose between three options: overwrite destination-file, append destination-file or cancel.

It should make the following argument checks:

- The number of arguments must be 2.
- The source-file must be a regular file.
- If the destination-file exists, it must be a regular file.

Can anyone help me how I would go about completing this task?

Comment: If the user wants a copy, you do `cp sourcefile destfile`. If they want to append, you do `cat sourcefile >> destfile`.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `help test` to do (a), (b) and (c).

Answer (score 0):

**An attempt to answer your 4 or 5 questions:** In the future, please ask a single question per post and make an attempt at answering it as all of this is pretty easily answered through google.

How to check [how many arguments are passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/check-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-bash-script) to the script

---

[Information on "test"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/check-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-bash-script). You can also use command `man test` to RTFM

**Some examples:**

1. Testing if it's a regular file (from the previous link) returns true/false:

   [ -f myfile ]
2. Testing if file exists (again from previous link)  returns true/false:

   [ -a myfile ]

---

[How to read user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226703/how-do-i-prompt-for-yes-no-cancel-input-in-a-linux-shell-script)

I think the "inline" bash version here is very nice for your needs:

```
read -p "Do you want to (C)opy, (A)ppend, or (E)nd? " answer
case ${answer:0:1} in
    c|C )
        cp file1 file2
    ;;
    a|A )
        cat file1 >> file2
    ;;
    * )
        echo "That's not an option, yo"
    ;;
esac
```

---

How to copy a file (after user makes selection)

```
cp file1 file2
```

How to append a file (after user makes selection)

```
cat file >> file2
```

Comment: *points to "Answer Well-Asked Questions" heading in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer*