# Adding one or two directories to PATH variable in linux ( Using Bash script)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So far
I have the following code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Adding new path...."
    if [[$# -eq1] || [$# -eq2]] 
    then
    if [$# -eq2] 
    then
    export PATH=$PATH:/$1:/$2
    fi
    if [$# -eq1] 
    then
    export PATH=$PATH:/$1
    fi
    else echo "Incorrect number of parameters. No more than two     directories can be added at once."
    fi
     echo $PATH
     exit 0
```

When I run this script passing it one parameter i get an error:
"./addDir: line 3: [[1: command not found
./addDir: line 3: [1: command not found "

when I run it with 2 parameters instead of "1" it says "2"

What's going on?

Comment: You need way more spaces on those conditions. `if [[ $# -eq 1 || $# -eq 2 ]]`

Comment: @Kevin (I think) that really should have been an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/check-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-bash-script/18568726

Comment: @DavidZ eh, I don't really have the patience to explain it right now.

Comment: @Kevin Sure, but I don't think that matters - the text you posted in the comment box could have been copied and pasted into the answer box and it would make a valid, albeit minimal, answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some spaces. Basically, if you're trying to use the `[...]` construction, you need to have spaces before and after each bracket - think of `[` as being the name of a command, in the same way as `echo`, and `]` as being an argument to that command. (In fact, there might actually be a `/bin/[` program on your system.) Just as you can't type `echofoo` and expect it to run the `echo` program, similarly you can't type `[[$#` if you expect it to run `[`.

In your case, you'd need to do things like

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; ...
```

And for the compound test you're doing in line 3, I don't think you can use `[` and `]` within the test. In other words, don't use those brackets for grouping; it has to be `[ something ]` where the `something` doesn't contain any brackets. Read the relevant section of the bash man page for the full details of what you *can* put there.

There is also a shell construct `[[ ... ]]` which does basically the same thing but has different syntax. You could use that instead, but be aware that it's very different from `[ ... ]`.