# How would I write an 'if' command that checks to see if there are multiple arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, fedora

I need to create a script that uses an 'if' command that checks whether there is exactly one argument. If there is more than one argument, I need it to echo “Usage: give exactly 1 argument, the string to be looked for” and then exit immediately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check number of arguments passed to a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/check-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

This should do the trick:

```
if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: give exactly 1 argument, the string to be looked for"
    exit 0
else
   echo the expected processing happens in this section of this code
fi
```