# Bash script: get number of input parameters excluding options

Tags: bash

I am creating a bash script for performing some file/folder comparisons.

I need the user to provide two files/folder paths and some options if needed (any different should close the program).

I would like to know how can I "catch" the number of input argument with the exclusion of options.

Here is some example code (file called foo):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

Help()
{
   # Display Help
   echo -e "I am the help menu"
}

############################################################    
# Main program                                             


# Process the input options. 
while getopts ":he" option; do
   case $option in
      h) # display Help
         Help
         exit;;
      e) # Exclude Files
         echo -e "e option was selected";;
     \?) # Invalid option
         echo -e "Error: Invalid option"
         exit;;
   esac
done

# Code to filter the input in order to have only two user inputs + options
file1=$1;
file2=$2;

echo -e file1
echo -e file2
```

So, if the user does: `foo -e "someparameter" file1 file2` it should work

if: `foo file1` should give an error.

How can I do this?

Best regards
if: `foo file1 file2 file3` should also give an error.

Comment: `if the user does: foo file1 file2 -e "someparameter" it should work` Then you can't use `getopts`. Options must be before positional arguments for `getopts`. Anyway, use GNU `getopt`. Why `-e` everywhere? Just `echo`.

Answer (score 3):

It is explained in the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getopts.1p.html).

> ```
> shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
> printf "Remaining arguments are: %s\n$*"
> ```

[Use `$#` to check the number of arguments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/check-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-bash-script)