# how to make two shell script into one in bash

Tags: bash

f1.sh

```
dweb=$1
web=$2

wget \
      --recursive \
      --no-clobber \
      --page-requisites \
      --html-extension \
      --convert-links \
      --restrict-file-names=windows \
      --domain $dweb \
      --no-parent \
         $web
```

f2.sh

```
web=$1

wget \
      --recursive \
      --no-clobber \
      --page-requisites \
      --html-extension \
      --convert-links \
      --restrict-file-names=windows \
      --no-parent \
         $web
```

I combine them in a new **mynewfunc.sh** file but it doesn't seem to work. f1.sh takes two args f2.sh takes one arg. How do I combine them using mynewfunc.sh without getting any errors so I can use one or two args using one .sh file.

Comment: just call them from another script: `sh <path_to_f1.sh>/f1.sh; sh <path_to_f2.sh>/f2.sh`

Comment: This is a repost of your earlier question: [how to combine two bash script function to a single sript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70092952/how-to-combine-two-bash-script-function-to-a-single-sript).

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is `$#` (the amount of parameters of a bash script). When this equals 1, you launch your first script. Otherwise you launch your second one. More information can be found in [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568706/check-number-of-arguments-passed-to-a-bash-script).